# How to solve unhandled Promise rejection from await messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, discord, discord.js

I am getting this error in my console:

```
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:33480) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 5)
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 6)
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 7)
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 8)
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 9)
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 10)
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 11)
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:92:53)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)      
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\RIJAK\Documents\GitHub\asta-jr\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:978:20)  
(node:33480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing 
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To 
terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 12)
```

and I have narrowed down the problem to this part of my code:

```
for (var x = 0; x < questions.length; x++) {
        message.author
          .send({
            embed: {
              title: `***Q${x + 1}. ${questions[x]}***`,
              description:
                "Please answer questions honestly and if asked about your details, please provide REAL life details",
              footer: {
                text: "You have 1 minute to answer questions!",
              },
              color: 0xe556f5,
            },
          })
          .then((msg) => {
            dmCh = msg.channel;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            message.author.send("Some error occurred");
          });
          dmCh.awaitMessages({ max: 1, time: 60000 })
            .then((answer) => {
              // answers.append(answer.toLowerCase());
              console.log(answer);
            })
            .catch((collected) => {
              // console.log(collected);
            });
      }
```

I have tried other commands of my bot and they work fine but as soon as I run this command, it gives the above-mentioned error and after this, if I type any message in the channel it gives this error.
I have also tried putting a try and catch block around my code like this:

```
try {
          dmCh.awaitMessages({ max: 1, time: 60000 })
            .then((answer) => {
              // answers.append(answer.toLowerCase());
              console.log(answer);
            })
            .catch((collected) => {
              // console.log(collected);
            });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
```

but it doesn't work.

Please help me!

Comment: Try updating djs to v13 if you haven't yet

Comment: [`dmCh = msg.channel;` does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron). Move the `msg.channel.awaitMessages(…)` *inside* the `then` callback

Comment: @Bergi I tried that but I still get this error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function
    at MessageCollector.handleCollect` I think the problem is occuring while collecting the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occures because you haven't provided a `filter` function.

Here's an example from the documentation

```js
// Await !vote messages
const filter = m => m.content.startsWith('!vote');

// Errors: ['time'] treats ending because of the time limit as an error
channel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 4, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
  .then(collected => console.log(collected.size))
  .catch(collected => console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 voted.`));
```

Documentation on [DmChannel#awaitMessages()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) (v13)

**If you're using v12**

```js
channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 4, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] }) //...
```

Comment: It doesn't work even after filter function

Comment: Does the error still occure? The documentation points to the v13 example, ensure you are using v13 or implement the filter according to the v12 documentation

Comment: I think it is trying to call the object as a function because it is in the filter argument spot. Due to this I believe they are in v12 and the filter must be the first argument

Comment: Thank You so much for the answer but is there a way to go back to v12? I kinda updated cuz I was stuck in this and now my code is broken.

Comment: You can do `npm uninstall discord.js` then `npm install discord.js@<VERSION>`. However it's best you learn v13 as v12 will be deprecated in the future

Answer (score 1):

The only part of the code shown in the question that looks like it could generate an unhandled rejection is the

```
message.author.send("Some error occurred");
```

in the `catch` handler. If that throws an error, it will reject the promise from `catch`, and that rejection isn't being handled anywhere.

You can catch that rejection by adding a second `catch` handler, or using `try`/`catch` inside the `catch` handler you have:

```
.catch(err => {
    try {
        message.author.send("Some error occurred");
    } catch (e) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

If `send` returns a promise, that won't handle the promise. To handle both throw exceptions *and* a rejection from `send`, return the result of `send` and add a second `catch` handler:

```
.catch(err => {
    return message.author.send("Some error occurred");
})
.catch(err => {
    // Do whatever you want to do when the error handling failed
});
```

---

But it's also possible that some function you're calling is creating a promise that it *isn't* passing back to your code, and failing to handle rejection of that promise.

Comment: I have tried that but it is still showing the same error. Moreover, I tried commenting out the await messages part and it stopped giving that error. So I think there is a problem with that. I have been trying to solve this since 2 hours but I just don't understand why there is a rejection...

Comment: @RijakSingh - That suggests that the last paragraph above applies: `dmCh.awaitMessages` is creating a promise it **doesn't** return, and failing to handle rejection of that promise.

Comment: read the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) on `awaitMessages()` - it gives some example code on how message collectors work.

Comment: Try awaiting `.send()` for error handling, as it also returns a promise

Comment: @Elitezen I tried that and now it doesn't give an error and sends the embed but as soon as i enter the answer it gives the following error: `(node:39544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is 
a object and not a function`

Comment: The problem occurs while collecting the message, can someone help?